# SpringBoot war and JNDI DataSource standalone not working

Tags: spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot2-Application configured as a war package that I want to run on the command-line but also be deployable in an application server.
Per the instructions, I configured the dependency to the embedded Tomcat to scope "provided" and also added a `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` to override the initialization of the embedded Tomcat so that I can enable `jndi.naming` because I want the datasource to be read from the jndi of the application server. In case I start the application standalone, I provide the jndi-resource by adding it to the embedded Tomcat during start.

This fails nicely: if the scope is "provided" and starting standalone, my `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` is not run and jndi is not activated so the lookup of the datasource fails. But that package works fine in Wildfly. If I remove "provided", the standalone application starts fine but it crashes in Wildfly out of obvious reasons (there is a Tomcat instance started to many that can not be cast to an Undertow-instance).

Has anybody else experienced this and has a solution? What does the SpringBoot-Maven plugin do to "hide" an embedded Tomcat in a war? Maybe my `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` has to adjust to the "provided"(hidden) configuration?

Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: Why? For local development just use a local database and only on the server use JNDI. Toggle the configuration using a profile.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I decided early on to not toggle the config using a profile. I'd like to double use the app as it is.

Comment: So you are basically want to make it more complex and error prone instead of using a default available mechanism (which was designed for exactly this). Nonetheless you must be doing something strange as the `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` should actually kick-in. However you probably want a `TomcatContextCustomizer` to do additional configuration.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer even if I want to go a different route than you expect. I'd be fine if using a custom TomcatServletWebServerFactory with a Tomcat dependency that's set to "provided" is considered to be not working by design because it's not wanted. Otherwise I'm pretty sure it's a bug. But I was hoping to find someone who attempted something similar and could share his/her experiences. Do you know what the SpringBoot-Maven plugin does to "hide" the embedded Tomcat when setting the dep to "provided"? A quick glance a the source did not really bring something up.

Comment: It places it in a different directory. But as I mentioned you probably want a `TomcatContextCustomizer` although it is indeed a bit weird that you don't really want Tomcat but still want to configure it.

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding going on. I want a Tomcat and I want to configure it - when running standalone. see [SpringBoot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging). Afaik `TomcatContextCustomizer` only let's you modify the context. But reading the stacktraces, the embedded Tomcat needs JNDI enabled which is what the `Factory` does.

Comment: Looking from a deployment POV you don't want tomcat, also to customize tomcat there are other customizer/processors available. So instead of trying to configure everything yourself you probably want to customize things.